# Extract text between given set of words using Python

Tags: python, string, python-re

I went through various answers before posting and they are all regular expression based and involve symbols and special characters.

Here is my input text and expected output. I want to extract the text between 'Investment Objective' and 'Investment Policy'

input_text

> "Investment Objective    To provide long        -  term capital growth by investing primarily in a portfolio of African companies.  Investment Policy"

output_text:

> "To provide long     -  term capital growth by investing primarily in a portfolio of African companies."

Comment: did you try anything? got error or wrong output?

Comment: But regular expressions are the way to go. `re.search(r"Investment Objective\s*(.*?)\s+Investment Policy", input_text).group(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Joshua's answer:

```
input_text="Investment Objective    To provide long        -  term capital growth by investing primarily in a portfolio of African companies.  Investment Policy"

start_str = "Investment Objective"
startpos = input_text.find(start_str)

end_str = "Investment Policy"
endpos = input_text.find(end_str)

output_str = input_text[startpos + len(start_str):endpos]
output_str_nospaces = output_str.strip()

print(f"'{output_str}'")
print(f"'{output_str_nospaces}'")
```

Which prints:

```
'    To provide long        -  term capital growth by investing primarily in a portfolio of African companies.  '
'To provide long        -  term capital growth by investing primarily in a portfolio of African companies.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, your blacklisted words are:

```
black = ["Investment Objective","Investment Policy"]
```

Now lets remove it:

```
for i in black:
    input_text = input_text.replace(i,'').strip()
```

this gives:

```
'To provide long        -  term capital growth by investing primarily in a portfolio of African companies.'
```

Comment: OP asked for just the part between the two strings. If another string also has text before and/or after the specified strings, those will not get deleted.